# How to send Back key in Robot framework Appium ? [Android]

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

Could anyone can help me how to send **Back Key** in Robot framework Appuim Android ? or Do i need to create custom library with python ? 
Thanks you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to send Back Key to Android Roboframework Appium by using

```
Press Keycode             4
```

- **Back is 4**
- **Menu is 82**
- **Recent Apps is 187 (APP_SWITCH)**

Comment: Simply including "Press Keycode    4" worked for me as well (with 4 spaces between "Keycode" and "4").